# How to drop a button over another in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have two `UIButtons` in a `ViewController`. One of them is dragable using `UIPanGesture` recogniser. I want to drop this dragable `UIButton` over a fixed `UIButton`. How can I achieve this?

This is what I tried:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(self.firstButton.frame, self.oneButton.frame))
{    
    [self.oneButton addSubview:self.firstButton];    //first button is the dragable button.
}
```

However I figured just adding as subview won't work. What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to achieve this? This seems like a really convoluted way of ui structure.

Comment: Well I have been asked to implement this feature in native iOS...it was in a certain web app

Comment: any reason you don't add it as subview of the viewcontrollers view?

Comment: What is the desired outcome? I.e how does adding as a subview not work?

Comment: I need to show an effect like...a button gets dragged over a button.

Comment: Imagine recycle bin...when we drag something over its icon...it goes away...something like that

Comment: @Sushrut If you want to remove it, just use [_firstButton removeFromSuperview].

Comment: If you want an object "on top" of another object you use addSubview.  But remember to first set the added object's frame appropriately, relative to the "superview" object.  And keep in mind that you need not add the object to the view of the overlaid object, but you can instead add to a common superview, so long as the added object's "Z order" is higher than the overlaid object.

Comment: You can perform this idea (of recycle bin) by checking the coordinates of the draggable button just before it is realised, and then check if any of it lies in the 'recycle button' area.